# Can't Set Fill Color Apache POI Excel Workbook

Tags: java, colors, background, apache-poi, fill

I have scanned this forum over and over and tried every method mentioned on here and still can't get Apache POI to change to fill background color of my excel document.

Here is my code:

```
errorOccured = true;
XSSFCellStyle cs = workbook.createCellStyle();
cs.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
row.getCell(0).setCellStyle(cs);
```

Do you know why this wouldn't work? What is the correct way to get `row.getCell(0)` to be filled with red (background color)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use foreground color instead of Background color.

```
 errorOccured = true;
 XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
 style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
 style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
 row.getCell(0).setCellStyle(style);
```

this will fill the cell background color with RED.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this still is not working for me. I do not know why. I am in debug mode and I confirm that the code is executed but it does not change any color in the .xlsx workbook. Any ideas? Does it have anything to do with the fact that the cells I am trying to turn red are ALREADY filled in with yellow fill?

Comment: Richie: In order to see the changes in the excel sheet, you need to perform Write command for this. Please confirm do the workbook.write(fileoutputstream) command executed before you have seen that in debug mode?

Comment: I apoligize for the delayed response. That was the issue! I did not realize you have the rewrite the file! Thank you very much, Rich.

Comment: @Sankumarsingh This issue has irritated me most... Thanks.

Comment: this works, though it's a bit strange to change the foreground in order to change the background

Comment: setFillPattern() is a key element.

Comment: Thank you! 30 min took me to find this answer :)

Comment: setFillPattern is depreciated

Comment: i could not make it work with LIght gray color as background or foreground. any help please?